# Can't open iPhone Configuration Utility while setting up push notification for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm following a tutorial to setup push notification for a iOS app. I got to a point where after creating and downloading a provisioning profile to test the app, I need to double click it to open it to specify a device to test the push notification on. Supposedly it should open the the **iPhone Configuration Utility**. However, when I double click on it, nothing happens. The file is a `.mobileprovision` and I'm running `OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.4`.

If you have any idea why this is happening and I could I fix it/work around it, that would be really appreciated if you could let me know.

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial?

Comment: It's actually a Udemy course lecture

Comment: You might want to have a quick look around for an alternate tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial). The step you mention above is not required with the suggested tutorial and it should give you enough to learn about pushing to iOS apps.